# how to get last record from many to many relationship with condition in laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

[Please look over this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Edb.jpg)

Phone: has many phone status

Phone_status: has many phone

But I whan phone status the latest status in phone_status table

In Phone model:

```
public function phoneStatus(){
  return $this->hasOne(PhoneStatus::class, 'phone_id','id')->latest();
}
```

Now, I want to get filter all phone that latest status is "sold".
Somethings like:

```
[
 id=> 1,
 name=> 'iphone XYZ',
 phonestatus => [
    phone_status => 'sold'
 ]
]
```

My code in controller:

```
 $getProjectData = Phone::whereHas('phoneStatus', function ($query) use 
       ($status) {
            $query->latest()->where('status', 'like', '%'. $status.'%');
        })->with(['phoneStatus' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('status', 'DESC');
        }]);
```

My proplem:
although the latest status is "restore" but $getProjectData alway return all phone have "sold" status.
Please help me to sovle :(

Answer (score 0):

In Phone model add this relationship

```
public function allStatus(){
return $this->hasOne(PhoneStatus::class, 'phone_id','id');
}
```

In controller

```
$getProjectData = Phone::whereHas('allStatus', function ($query) use 
       ($status) {
            $query->where('status', 'like', '%'. $status.'%');
        })->with(['allStatus' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 'like', '%'. $status.'%')->orderBy('status', 'DESC');
        }])->get();
```

Comment: this code in controller still return all items have 'sold' status, althought the latest status is 'restore''